# shortest path in complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete connected by arcs metric space. We define the length of a continuous path $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow X$ to be
\begin{equation*}
\sup\limits_{0=a_{0}<a_{1}<... a_{n}=1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} d(\gamma(a_{i}),\gamma(a_{i+1})).
\end{equation*}

If two given points are joined by a path of finite length, is there necessarily a path of minimum length joining them ? I do not know the answer to this question.

What I do know is that if $X$ is compact then the answer is yes. A sketch of proof goes as follows: prove that length is invariant by reparametrization, then that every path of length $l$ has an $(l+\varepsilon)$-lipschitz reparametrization, and then apply Arzela-Ascoli's theorem. I found this exercise (with compact $X$) in a French book, Amar and Matheron's "Analyse complexe".

Comment: It is sufficient that every closed ball is compact, but I do not know what happens if this is also dropped...

Comment: The answer is negative, according to Exercise 2.5.24 in *Metric Geometry* by Burago, Burago, and Ivanov. Sadly, I can't think of an example right now.

Comment: In the $1$-Wasserstein space on $\mathbb{R}$, let $\mu_0:=\delta_0$, $\mu_1:=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum \frac{1}{n^2} \delta_{n}$. The 1-Wasserstein between them is $\sim\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} $, hence no path with finite length will ever connect them.

Comment: @Milly An example of that kind could be simpler: take an unrectifiable curve such as the Koch snowflake. It's even compact. Sergio should add the assumption that the space is connected by *rectifiable* arcs; it's implicitly used in the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: Well if the minimum distance between the two points is $+\infty$, then any path is shortest path... But I'll edit the post anyway

Comment: @Milly: the question is not about the existence of an arc of length equal to distance, but of length equal to distance in length metric. If there is no path of finite length connecting two points, then the length distance is $\infty$.

Comment: The paper _ARCS AND GEODESICS IN METRIC SPACES_ by S.B. Myers seems to mention a result similar to this for _locally compact_ spaces, extending the result you seem to mention for compact metric spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abstract idea: connect two points $A,B$ by a countable family of arcs $\gamma_n$ so that the length of $\gamma_n$ is $1+1/n$.

Concrete realization: in the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ with standard basis $\{e_0,e_1,\dots\}$, consider the points $A=e_0$, $B=-e_0$, and $C_n = (1+1/n)e_n$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. All these are at distance at least $1$ from one another. Let $X$ be the union of line segments $AC_n$ and $BC_n$ over $n=1,2,\dots$. This set is rectifiably connected: indeed, one can get from any point to $A$ by traveling along two line segments at most.

There is no shortest path from  $A$ to $B$:  traveling along $AC_nB$ takes distance $$2\sqrt{1+(1+1/n)^2}$$
which can be arbitrarily close to $2\sqrt{2}$ but never equal to it.

Completeness of $X$ follows from the fact that it's a closed subset of $\ell^2$.

Comment: Actually, you have to be a bit more careful here: If $(X,d)$ is a path-metric space and $Y$ is a rectifiable subset of $X$, then the topology on $Y$ coming from its  induced path-metric $d_p$ is, in general, different from the subspace topology (take a version of the topologist's sine curve as an example). Therefore, a priori, a closed rectifiable subset of X need not be complete with respect to its path-metric. (I cannot think of any examples of this phenomenon, though.) What is clear though is that a Cauchy sequence in $(Y, d_p)$ implies Cauchy in $(X,d)$.

Comment: The assumptions did not specify that $X$ should be complete in the path metric; in fact the path metric is not even introduced in the question. So I interpreted completeness in the norm metric coming from $\ell^2$. As it happens, my $X$ is quasiconvex, so the path metric is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the norm metric.

Comment: Oh, I see: I misread the question: I was thinking about path-metrics.