# path metrics without geodesics

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994260/shortest-path-in-complete-metric-space/995956?noredirect=1#comment2036942_995956). Recall that a metric space $(X,d)$ is called a *path-metric space* if the distance between any two points in $X$ equals the infimum of lengths of paths between these points. Such $(X,d)$ contains a plenty of rectifiable paths (unless $X$ is either empty or is a one-point set). A *geodesic* between the two points $x, y\in X$ is a 
path $c$ from $x$ to $y$, whose length equals the distance $d(x,y)$.

**Question.** Is there a complete path-metric space $(X,d)$ (of infinite cardinality) such the only geodesics in $(X,d)$ are constant maps to $X$? (I think so, but do not see a clear proof.)

Obviously, such space $X$ cannot be locally compact (at any point).

Note that in the example given in the linked question, there are pairs of points without geodesics connecting them. Another example (an infinite-dimensional complete Hilbert manifold) is mentioned in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem). However, in both examples, the space contains plenty of geodesics (Hilbert manifolds always do).

**Edit.** I just discovered that the same question was posted (in 2010) and answered on Mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15592/intrinsic-metric-with-no-geodesics?rq=1).

Comment: cross-posted on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186752/path-metrics-without-geodesics (btw, you say it was the wrong place here, but I think what you did is the right procedure: first ask on mathSE and then go to mathOF if no good answer here)

Comment: @YCor: Agree, I removed that statement from the MO question.

Comment: Actually, I think the correct way is to flag this question for moving to MO. This helps search engines and avoids answer/comments duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to close the question:

The same question was posted (in 2010) and answered on Mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15592/intrinsic-metric-with-no-geodesics?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

Just an extended comment (initially an answer but I misread the question): here's an example that is not complete.

Consider the union $D$ of all circles in the Euclidean plane of rational center and nonzero rational radius, with the distance induced from $\mathbf{R}^2$.

1) This is a length (=path) metric space. Indeed, pick $x,y\in D$ and fix $\varepsilon>0$. Pick a little open piece of circle $X\subset D$, of radius $\le\varepsilon$, through $x$, and similarly $Y$ through $y$. The set of lines intersecting both $X$ and $Y$ has non-empty interior, hence contain a rational line; using this, we can find a rational line $E$ intersecting both $X$ and $Y$; it contains rational points at $x',y'$ at distance $\le\varepsilon$ of $x$ resp $y$. The bisector line of $[x',y']$ is rational, hence we can find pieces of circle with rational center far away on this bisector line, that are arbitrary close to the segment $[x',y']$, and eventually these circles do intersect $X$ and $Y$. This yields a path in $D$ from $x$ to $y$ with, say, length $\le d(x,y)+(1+\pi)\varepsilon$.

2) The space $D$ contains no segment. Indeed the intersection of each line with a circle consists of at most 2 points, and hence the intersection of each line with $D$ is countable.